# Constantly refreshing background image of UIImageView IOS

Tags: ios, xcode

How would I constantly refresh a background image of my UIImageView, while also still listening for touches and input? What I am looking for is the iOS Objective C equivalent (in java) of creating a new thread apart from the main thread, and having  that thread be devoted to updating the background picture as fast as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where the new images are coming from. If they are a cycle of known existing images in your app bundle, just make this an animated image view (or an animated image) and the cycle will happen automatically.

If you need to run code e.g. to get out to the network periodically, then just start a repeating NSTimer. It calls you on the main thread, but your main thread code will be very brief indeed, and networking takes place asynchronously (unless you mess that up deliberately). Just make sure that when you actually *set* the image, you step out to the main thread, as you must *never* touch the interface in any way except on the main thread.

Comment: Ok, so im getting the image from a URL, So I need to use the NSTimer method

Comment: This should be no problem. NSTimer is simple, and, as I told you, network operations are asynchronous (they don't block, since they are using background threads). Keep in mind, though, that network usage is resource-expensive and your users will take revenge if your app runs the battery down (or if they discover that you are using the network "secretly"). Also, I need hardly point out that network usage can fail; the network can vanish, the user can turn off the radios, etc. This is a risky strategy; be prepared.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, I will definitely need to address those things very carefully. I am making an app that works kind of like TeamViewer so heavy network use will be apparent to the user. I am hoping I can find a way to not drain the battery haha.